# getting error "Cannot read property appendchild of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div class="commentArea"></div>
<input class="write" type="text">
<button onclick="summitComment()" class="summit">summit</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

```
function summitComment() {
    let comments = document.getElementsByClassName('commentArea')[0];

    let makeDiv = document.createElement('div');
    makeDiv.className = 'talking';

    comments.appendChild(makeDiv)

    let makeUser = document.createElement('span');
    let makeMsg = document.createElement('span');
    let makeBtn = document.createElement('button');

    makeUser.className = "commentUserId";
    makeMsg.className = "mentionUserComment";
    makeBtn.className = "deleteReply"; 

    makeMsg.innerHTML = reply.value;
    makeUser.innerHTML = "User_ID";
    makeBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";

    for (i=0; 1; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('talking')[i].appendChild(makeUser)
        document.getElementsByClassName('talking')[i].appendChild(makeMsg)
        document.getElementsByClassName('talking')[i].appendChild(makeBtn)
    }
}
```

I'm studying javascript and I try to make comment section for webpage.
first code is HTML code and second is JS code.
but when I write something and click summit button, it's work. but console shows to me error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

I think The tag created by 'createElement' does not seem to be chosen by getElementsByClassName.

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Issue is in the for loop. Idk what is the purpose of a loop here. I'm not sure if the syntax you have here for the loop is allowed in javascript. The error comes during the second iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `appendChild` cannot read from `undefined`
You need check Element exist before append instead of:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('talking');
for (i=0; 1; i++) {
    element?.[i]?.appendChild(makeUser)
    element?.[i]?.appendChild(makeMsg)
    element?.[i]?.appendChild(makeBtn)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `reply` variable was not defined and this loop on the end I don't think it's needed

```js
function summitComment() {
    let comments = document.getElementsByClassName('commentArea')[0];
    let reply = document.querySelector('.write');

    let makeDiv = document.createElement('div');
    makeDiv.className = 'talking';

    comments.appendChild(makeDiv);

    let makeUser = document.createElement('span');
    let makeMsg = document.createElement('span');
    let makeBtn = document.createElement('button');

    makeUser.className = "commentUserId";
    makeMsg.className = "mentionUserComment";
    makeBtn.className = "deleteReply";

    makeMsg.innerHTML = reply.value;
    makeUser.innerHTML = "User_ID";
    makeBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";

    
    makeDiv.appendChild(makeUser)
    makeDiv.appendChild(makeMsg)
    makeDiv.appendChild(makeBtn)
}
```

```html
<div class="commentArea"></div>
<input class="write" type="text">
<button onclick="summitComment()" class="summit">summit</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
`if (!!comment) comments.appendChild(makeDiv)`
instead of only
`comments.appendChild(makeDiv)`

Answer (score -1):

getElementByClassName returns a single DOM element. You don't need to do '[0]' on it. Remove that and it should work fine.

In case if you use querySelectorAll, then you have get by index since this method returns an array.

Comment: The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s)